# Is it possible to rename "function" in JS?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

For instance can a write a function using

```
ಠ(){}
```

instead of

```
function(){}
```

Note: ಠ is a valid identifier according to ECMAScript 6 / Unicode 8.0.0. 

https://mothereff.in/js-variables

Comment: You're asking if you can change the language's keywords?

Comment: `function` is not an identifier.

Comment: You can certainly do the following: `var ಠ = function(){};`.

Comment: or create an alias for them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest thing you can do is alias the [`Function` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function):

```js
var ಠ = Function;
```

But that won't let you define functions in exactly the same way, the usage would be:

```
ಠ("arg1","arg2","alert('function body');if(typeof(ಠ) !== 'undefined')alert('you\'ve done a very bad thing');");
```

You probably *shouldn't* do this, though, unless you're going for some sort of golf challenge, obfuscation shenanigans, or you're making a small joke site and want to make it harder (or more amusing) for people to read your code. Don't do this for anything serious. *Please.*

Comment: @BryanGrace Eh, probably a decent metric is when other people are looking at it more than once?

Comment: Thank you! That could beautufy my code. It could be `let add = fn("x, y, x+y")` instead of `function add(x,y) { return x + y; }` or `let add = (x,y) => x + y`. The `fn` can split on `,` and return a `new Function`.

Answer (score 6):

No, you cannot.

You might be able to use something like Sweet or another JS transpiler.

The logical question that nobody has asked yet is *why*? My first reaction is that this is an X/Y problem, since `function` doesn't seem particularly onerous on its own.

Comment: ....because I want to use my midi controller as a second keyboard and I like hieroglyphics.  Maybe I'm the only one...

Comment: @BryanGrace: It certainly makes your code unreadable, if not to everyone at least to all but you. Can't you configure your midi controller to insert the whole `function` keyword?

Comment: Definitely, in terms of unreadability though it would just be a matter of reading up on the transpiler docs... I guess... #noBiggie

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like `function(){}` you can use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) in ES6.

> **Disclaimer:** arrow functions lexically bind the `this` value

---

```
var add = function(x,y) { return x + y; };
```

Can be written as

```
let add = (x,y) => x + y;
```

---

It's significantly less verbose when you start nesting functions too

```
var add = function(x) {
  return function(y) {
    return x + y;
  };
};
```

Can be written as

```
let add = x => y => x + y;
```

Comment: I have never seen `=>` so perspicuous! The nesting you show is *currying* that become useful when understood.